# Please help to show the following identity

Tags: integration, summation, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

How can I prove the following identity ?
$$
k \binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{\binom{k-1}{i}(-1)^i}{(n-k+1+i)} e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-k+1+i)}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i} (1-e^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}})^ie^{-\frac{T}{\theta_1}(n-i)}.
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the following identity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029988/how-to-find-the-following-identity)

Comment: Isn't the RHS Similar to $$X\sim Bin\left(n,1-e^{-{T\over \theta _1}}\right)$$ and the RHS is $$P(X\le k-1)$$ ?

Comment: @RobertZ yes sure ! I have deleted it from the forum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=e^{\frac{T}{\theta_1}}$. Then the RHS is
$$z^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i} (z-1)^i=z^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i} \sum_{j=0}^i(-1)^{i-j}\binom{i}{j} z^{j}=
z^{-n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^jz^{j}\sum_{i=j}^{k-1}(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{j}.$$
Now the inner sum gives 
$$\frac{(-1)^{k-1} k}{n-j}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k-1}{j}.$$
Therefore
$$\mbox{RHS}=z^{-n}k\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{j-(k-1)}}{n-j}\binom{k-1}{j}z^{j}=z^{-n}k\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{j-(k-1)}}{n-j}\binom{k-1}{k-1-j}z^{j}\\
=k\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{i}}{n-(k-1-i)}\binom{k-1}{i}z^{k-1-i-n}
$$
which is equal to the LHS.

Comment: how do you justify  the formula for the inner sum

Comment: This is a known identity. The proof is similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860455/how-to-prove-sum-k-m1n-1k-binomnk-binomk-1m-1m1

Comment: @pinku Any further doubt? BTW the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted" ;-). http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: good way to ask rep!!