# Does this combinatorial identity hold？

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, differential-topology, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove
$$\sum\limits_{k=i+1}^m (-1)^{k-1+i}\binom{m}{k}\binom{k-1}{i}=1,$$ where $m\geq 1, 1\leq i\leq m-1$. Actually this is what I induce when I'm trying to calculate what the tangent map of $\log：\text{PD}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \text{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is， where $\text{PD}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the positive-definite matrix, $\text{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the symmetric matrix, and $\log$ is the inverse map of $\exp$. If this identity holds, I can directly write out the formula of tangent map. But I stuck at this step.

Comment: Have you tried specifying small values of $m$ and $i$ first?

Comment: It is not hold, $i=1$ is true, but when $i=2$, it gives $3-m$, fails.

Comment: These get tricky, but yes, it does seem to hold. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5B%5C%2891%29Power%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Ck-1%2Bc%5D%5C%2840%29m+choose+k%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29k-1%5C%2841%29+choose+c%5C%2841%29%5C%2893%29%2C%7Bk%2Cc%2B1%2Cm%7D%5D)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove: $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k-1}{m}= (-1)^{m+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860455/how-to-prove-sum-k-m1n-1k-binomnk-binomk-1m-1m1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Di%2B1%7D%5Em%20(-1)%5E%7Bk-1%2Bi%7D%5Cbinom%7Bm%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cbinom%7Bk-1%7D%7Bi%7D%3D1%24&p=1). Their expression is basically the same: first multiply by $(-1)^{i+1}$ to get $\sum_{k=i+1}^m(-1)^{k}\binom{m}{k}\binom{k-1}{i}=(-1)^{i+1}$, then replace $m$ with $n$ and $i$ with $m$.

Answer (score 6):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^i]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^i$ in a series.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^m}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{k-1+i}\binom{m}{k}\binom{k-1}{i}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k-1+i}\binom{m}{k}[z^i](1+z)^{k-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^{i-1}[z^i]\frac{1}{1+z}\sum_{k=1}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^k(1+z)^k\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^{i-1}[z^i]\frac{1}{1+z}\left(\left(1-(1+z)\right)^m-1\right)\\
> &=(-1)^{i-1}[z^i]\frac{1}{1+z}\left((-z)^m-1\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^{i}[z^i]\frac{1}{1+z}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we start with index $k=1$ noting that $\binom{k-1}{i}=0$ if $1\leq k\leq i$.
- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^i]$.
- in (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and rearrange the sum to apply the binomial theorem in the next step.
- In (4) we note that $(-z)^m$ does not contribute to $[z^i]$, since $i<m$.
- In (5) we use the geometric series expansion $[z^i]\frac{1}{1+z}=[z^i]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-z)^j=(-1)^i$.

**Hypergeometric functions:**

Here is another variation based upon *[hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)*. We use the rising factorials notation $(a)_{k}:=a(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)$.

> Assuming $m\geq 1$ and $1\leq i\leq m-1$ we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=i+1}^m}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{k-1+i}\binom{m}{k}\binom{k-1}{i}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{m-i-1}\underbrace{(-1)^k\binom{m}{k+i+1}\binom{k+i}{i}}_{=:t_k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{m-i-1}t_k=t_0\sum_{k=0}^{m-i-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{t_{j+1}}{t_j}\\
> &=\binom{m}{i+1}\sum_{k=0}^{m-i-1}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}
> (-1)^{k+1}\binom{m}{j+i+2}\binom{j+1+i}{i}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdot(-1)^{-k}
> \binom{m}{j+i+1}^{-1}\binom{j+i}{i}^{-1}\\
> &=\binom{m}{i+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}
> \frac{\left(j+i+1\right)\left(j+i+1-m\right)}{\left(j+1\right)\left(j+i+2\right)}\\
> &=\binom{m}{i+1}\sum_{k=0}^{m-i-1}\frac{(i+1)_k(i+1-m)_k}{(i+2)_k}\,\frac{1}{k!}\\
> &=\binom{m}{i+1}{_2F_1}\left(i+1,i+1-m;i+2;1\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{m}{i+1}\,\frac{\Gamma(i+2)\Gamma(m-i)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(m+1)}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the sum as hypergeometric $_2F_1$ function evaluated at $z=1$ with parameter $i+1-m$ a non-positive integer.
- In (2) we recall a theorem from C. F. Gauss [1812] (see e.g. Theorem 2.2.2 in *[Special Functions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/special-functions/1F1C575CEA780EE774F5518C7963BF08#fndtn-information)* by G.E. Andrews, R. Askey and R. Roy) which is
  \begin{align*}
  {_2F_1}(a,b;c;1)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}
  \end{align*}
  if $\Re(c-a-b)>0$. We derive from (1) $\Re\left((i+2)-(i+1)-(i+1-m)\right)=m-i>0$ and get
  \begin{align*}
  {_2F_1}(i+1,i+1-m;i+2;1)&=\frac{\Gamma(i+2)\Gamma(m-i)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(m+1)}\\
  &=\frac{(i+1)!(m-i-1)!}{m!}=\binom{m}{i+1}^{-1}
  \end{align*}

Comment: FYI, you basically used the first method in your solution above in your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1861255) to the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Ok, I see. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$F(m, k, i) = (-1)^{k - 1 + i} {m \choose k} {k - 1 \choose i}$$ be your summand. Note that it satisfies the creative telescoping recurrence

$$(i - m) F(m + 1, k, i) - (i - m) F(m, k, i) = \Delta_k \frac{k(i + 1 - k)}{k - m - 1} F(m, k, i),$$ where $\Delta_k$ is the forward shift operator in $k$.

If we let $f(m, i)$ be your sum and sum this identity from $k = i + 1$ to $k = m + 1$, then we obtain

$$(i - m) f(m + 1, i) - (i - m) f(m, i) = 0.$$

(The right-hand side is zero because the fraction vanishes at $k = i + 1$ and $F(m, k, i)$ vanishes for $k > m$.) If $i \neq m$, it follows that $f(m + 1, i) = f(m, i)$. Plugging in, say $m = i + 1$, we get

$$f(i + 1, i) = (-1)^{i + 1 - 1 + i} {i + 1 \choose i + 1} {i \choose i} = 1,$$

so $f(m, i) = 1$ for all $m > i$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: there was a typo in the question, so this answer is not yet relevant.

For $i=2$, $m=4$:
$$
\sum_{k=3}^4 (-1)^{k+1} \binom{4}{k}\binom{k-2}{2}
= \binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{2} - \binom{4}{4}\binom{2}{2}
= 0 - 1 = -1 \neq 1.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's a typo that I copied it with a letter wrong. Sorry for the confusion it bring about.